# How do you add to time value returned by date?

Tags: bash, date, date-arithmetic

I'm using the date function and trying to add minutes to the returned time (if it exceeds 60 it doesn't matter) 
but every time I add to the time it removes the leading 0 and returns an odd value

```
time=$(date +%R)
time=$(sed -e 's/://g' <<< $time)
start=$(($time + 0051))
echo $start
```

output should be 4 digit ie 0445

edit: it's being treated as octal because of the leading 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add 51 minutes to the current time with GNU date:

```
date "+%R" -d "+51 min"
```

Output (e.g.):

```
08:18
```